# error C2664: 'way' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'int' to 'int &'

Tags: c++

I'm having problem with a code.

This is my main.

```
int main()
{
    cin>>xG>>yG;
    int x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    int crrWay[200] = {0},
        minWay[200] = {0},
        minWayN = -1;
    way(x, y, crrWay, 0, 0, minWay, minWayN, 0);
    printWay(minWay, minWayN);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function.

```
void way(int x, int y, int *crrWay, int& crrWayWeight, int l, int* minWay, int& minWayN, int& minWayWeight)
{
    crrWay[2*l] = x;
    crrWay[2*l+1] = y;

    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 10 || y > 10 )
        return;

    // Сравнява намерения път с минималния
    if(x == xG && y == xG)
    {
        registerWay(crrWay, l+1, minWay, minWayN, crrWayWeight, minWayWeight);
        return;
    }

    // Клетката е непроходима.
    if(tempMaze[x][y]==0)
        return;
    tempMaze[x][y] = 0;
    crrWayWeight+=maze[x][y];

    // Рекурсивни обръщения към всеки от четирите съседа
    way(x+1, y, crrWay, crrWayWeight, l+1, minWay, minWayN, minWayWeight);
    way(x, y+1, crrWay, crrWayWeight, l+1, minWay, minWayN, minWayWeight);
    way(x-1, y, crrWay, crrWayWeight, l+1, minWay, minWayN, minWayWeight);
    way(x, y-1, crrWay, crrWayWeight, l+1, minWay, minWayN, minWayWeight);

    // връщане назад
    tempMaze[x][y] = 1;
}
```

The code can't compile. It says

> 1>c:\users\admin\documents\zad51.cpp(102): error C2664: 'way' : cannot
>   convert parameter 4 from 'int' to 'int &'

Comment: Why would you be able to pass in a literal as a reference? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `way` function takes non-const references `int&`, and you are passing temporaries such as `0`. Non-const references cannot bind to temporaries. You need to change the signature to take const references, or, if the function actually mutates the ints refered to, do not pass temporaries.

```
void way(int x, int y, int *crrWay, const int& crrWayWeight, int l, int* minWay, const int& minWayN, const int& minWayWeight);
```

or

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
way(x, y, crrWay, a, b, minWay, minWayN, c);
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Only option left is to +1 I guess!

Comment: He cannot change signature to take const reference, as crrWayWeight **is** modified inside function.

Answer (score 1):

The `way` function takes a reference to an integer as its fourth argument. You can't pass a literal (aka rvalue). A reference to an object is always an lvalue or a variable. What you should do is make a variable and pass that to the function call instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to pass constant literal as fourth argument. Assign it to variable i.e.:

```
int variable = 0;
way(x, y, crrWay, variable, 0, minWay, minWayN, 0);
```